# onClick functions executes twice

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

I'm trying to get JavaScript to execute correctly when either clicking a `checkbox`, or clicking a `<tr>`. However it seems to be executing the code twice; once for the `checkbox` and once for the `<tr>`.

Now you may say "Why not just put it on the checkbox and be done with it?" If it was that simple, I would have done that. But it was requested to have it trigger when they click the `<tr>` or on the `checkbox`.

Now to add some more complexity, when the `onClick` fires, it sends the data back to the parent, in an array, for processing until it is time for the update.

Child Window (Problem area)

```
function FnSearch(urembroid, embroideryID){
  if (document.getElementById("embroid"+embroideryID).checked == false){
                    try {
                            parent.window.EmbroideryDataReturned("add", embroideryID);
                    } catch(e) {
                            window.opener.parent.EmbroideryDataReturned("add", embroideryID);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("embroid"+embroideryID).checked = true;
            } else {
                    try {
                            parent.window.EmbroideryDataReturned("remove", embroideryID);
                    } catch(e) {
                            window.opener.parent.EmbroideryDataReturned("remove", embroideryID);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("embroid"+embroideryID).checked = false;
            }
```

Child window HTML -- Please note PHP is making the  and  fields.

```
echo "<tr id='embroideryData' onclick=\"javascript:FnSearch('" . $data['urembroidid'] . "', '".$data['EmbroideryID']."')\">"; // On a <tr> execute the update
    if (OrderKeyExists($data['EmbroideryID'])) {
            echo "<td id='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' id='embroid".$data['EmbroideryID']."' checked='checked'/></td>";
    } else {
            echo "<td id='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' id='embroid".$data['EmbroideryID']."'/></td>";
    }
echo "</tr>\n";
```

I only need this code to execute once. The code works correctly when clicking on the `<tr>` but executes twice when the `checkbox` is clicked on. However it also messes up the array inside the parent window to where it could have `false` data when clicking on the `checkbox`. When debugging, it sends a `onClick` to `FnSearch` as if the `checkbox` was originally "`checked`" when it was not. So it sends a "`remove`" to the parent, but the second time it does the complete opposite. This is causing the data integrity.

So the main question is: How do you get the `checkbox` to only execute `FnSearch` once?

If anyone has any input, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you're asking a JS question, it would be better to just show the HTML that's in the discussion instead of the PHP that produces the HTML. It just makes it easier to read.

Comment: The checkbox, when clicked fires off an event. This event is then bubbled up to the td then to the tr elements. Either move the event to the checkbox (where it actually belongs) or prevent the event from bubbling to the next level.

Comment: @jeff Then is there a way to prevent the checkbox from firing off its own event or to catch it and use it?

Comment: @Twister1002 if you cancel the event from the checkbox then your function will not execute. As for using the actual event - place the onclick event function in the checkbox.

Comment: @jeff if the onclick from the checkbox is canceled, then it would still  execute from the `<tr>`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of fixing it...

**(1)** This is the way I fixed same issue...because I also wanted custom checkboxes...

You can use images of checked and unchecked boxes instead of checkbox and toggle the src on `tr` click...

Also you have provided same id `checkbox` to all `td` which wont work...

```
function toggleRowSelection(row){
   if(row.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src == "checked.jpg")
       row.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "unchecked.jpg"
   else
       row.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "checked.jpg"
}
```

HTML (approx.)

```
<tr onclick="toggleRowSelection(this)"><td><img src="checked.jpg"></td></tr>
<tr onclick="toggleRowSelection(this)"><td><img src="checked.jpg"></td></tr>
```

**(2)** Get the element which is clicked in the row using [**event.target**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp) and if it is `td` check/uncheck the checkbox.....

and if it is `checkbox` just perform your operations

**(3)** Also check **`event.preventDefault()`** and **`event.stopPropagation()`** ...it might help you

Comment: Is there a way to just prevent the checkbox from taking any actions?

Comment: check the 3rd point... `event.stopPropagation()` is used to stop the click event propagation on parent elements....